Snowflake SQL Pivot/Transpose rows based on variable group
Here is a sample of my starting data table

I want to flip the data to look like the following - where for each unique combination of state fips, year, and id there are status1-status?. The number of status values is unknown and can vary based on the data.

I have been looking at pivot but can't seem to get the syntax correct. The documentation uses aggregation but I just need to transpose the information.
Here is some code and some of my attempts.
create or replace temporary table try1
(fips integer, yr integer, id varchar(5), status varchar(10));

insert into try1
values
(20,2022,47250,'03 ACTIVE'),
(20,2022,47250,'79 TERM'),
(20,2023,47250,'79 TERM'),
(20,2022,56957,'83 TERM'),
(20,2023,56957,'03 ACTIVE'),
(20,2023,56957,'83 TERM'),
(20,2022,57645,'79 TERM'),
(20,2023,57645,'03 ACTIVE'),
(20,2023,57645,'79 TERM'),
(20,2023,57645,'83 TERM');

select *, 1 as flag from try1
pivot(sum(flag)) for status in (any order status)
order by id;

select *, 1 as flag from try1
pivot(flag) for status in (any order status)
order by id;

select * from try1
pivot(for status in (any order status))
order by id;


Would you be ok having all statuses in one column? You can parse downstream.

I don't understand - all of the statuses are already 1 column now.  I want to transpose them to multiple columns per group.

I believe that @demircioglu was suggesting having them in one column, but perhaps in an array or comma delimited list or similar. Since the number of output columns is unknown, storing them in an array (for example) would you allow you to accomplish this in plain sql and still have the advantage of being query-able. There isn't any way to get the output you want without resorting to dynamic sql, or python/pyspark or similar non-SQL methods.

as others suggestions to parse it later you can use array_unique_agg
with try1(fips, yr, id, status ) as (
    select * from values
    (20,2022,47250,'03 ACTIVE'),
    (20,2022,47250,'79 TERM'),
    (20,2023,47250,'79 TERM'),
    (20,2022,56957,'83 TERM'),
    (20,2023,56957,'03 ACTIVE'),
    (20,2023,56957,'83 TERM'),
    (20,2022,57645,'79 TERM'),
    (20,2023,57645,'03 ACTIVE'),
    (20,2023,57645,'79 TERM'),
    (20,2023,57645,'83 TERM')
)
select 
    fips,
    yr,
    id,
    array_unique_agg(status) as status_array
from try1
group by 1,2,3
order by 1,3,2;


What your asked for
with try1(fips, yr, id, status ) as (
    select * from values
    (20,2022,47250,'03 ACTIVE'),
    (20,2022,47250,'79 TERM'),
    (20,2023,47250,'79 TERM'),
    (20,2022,56957,'83 TERM'),
    (20,2023,56957,'03 ACTIVE'),
    (20,2023,56957,'83 TERM'),
    (20,2022,57645,'79 TERM'),
    (20,2023,57645,'03 ACTIVE'),
    (20,2023,57645,'79 TERM'),
    (20,2023,57645,'83 TERM')
), classify as (
    select 
        *,
        'status_' || dense_rank() over (partition by fips, yr, id order by status )::int as s
    from try1
)
SELECT *
  FROM classify
    PIVOT(MIN(status) FOR s IN (ANY ORDER BY s))
  ORDER BY 1,3,2;
;



I didn't know about array_unique_agg(). I would have naively gone with array_agg(DISTINCT status) and cheated myself out of some syntactic sugar. Do you know if there is any pro/con between the two?

I only just found it when searching for the doc's link for array_agg, so first time user. But most speicalised function tell the optimizer more of what is intended to happen, so better parrellel performance can be had. So I lean into those functions myself.

Thank you- I will work with the sample code to see if it meets my needs.
